# Swift 3 Send Email with Attachment Ambiguous Expression

Tags: swift

I am trying to set up an email view controller using `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` with the following code:

```
let fileName = "test.csv"

   let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

 if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let emailController = MFMailComposeViewController()
            emailController.mailComposeDelegate = self
            emailController.setToRecipients(["testemail.com"])
            emailController.setSubject("Test Email")
            emailController.setMessageBody("Test Message", isHTML: false)
            emailController.addAttachmentData(NSData(contentsOfURL: path)!, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "test.csv")
            present(emailController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

The above throws an `error` on the `addAttachmentData` line is,

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you using `NSData` instead of `Data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two expressions instead of one:

```
    let data = Data(contentsOf: path)!
 emailController.addAttachmentData(data, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "test.csv")
```

Comment: now im getting error on the `let data` line saying `ambiguous use of init(contentsofurl)`

Comment: @Martheli ok. i've changed the code into swift 3 coding style